# How to make Intellij Idea's Intellisense work on C++ and Kotlin on a Flutter project?

Tags: android, kotlin, intellij-idea, intellisense

Due to opening a Flutter project into Intellij Idea, that is, opening the folder that contains both an Android project and an iOS project, Intellij Idea does not recognize the Android gradle project and thus both C++ and Kotlin intellisense won't work. I have to open one instance for the android project and another for the flutter project.

Having everything on one window is much better, specially if you develop inside docker using the docker plugin. Also it consumes much less RAM.

Opening thins in Android Studio also has this same problem.

So, how can I use C++ and Kotlin intellisense on Intellij Idea/Android Studio in a Flutter project?

Comment: does View Menu -> Tool Windows -> logcat working to show logcat tab?

Comment: @Priyankagb yes, works for logcat

Comment: You might check `Preferences -> Editor -> Language Injections`.

Comment: There should be an IDE action called something like *Import Gradle Project*. I believe it should work when you import the main `build.gradle` file of the android project

Comment: @JensV couldn't find such option

Answer (score 1):

What usually works for me in these situations is to use [modules](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html). That is, you create one project and add both the Android project and Flutter project as a module (you can basically look at a module as a sub-project). How I usually go about this is as follows.

1. Create a new project from existing sources by going to **File > New > Project from Existing Sources** and select the root folder of one of your modules.
2. Create a new module from existing sources by going to **File > New > Module from Existing Sources** and select the root folder of your other module.

You should now have one project (and thus one instance of IntelliJ or Android Studio) that contains your sub-projects as modules, and the autocompletion should be available for both of them.

**Note.** You can view all the modules currently in your project in the project settings (**File > Project Structure** or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>) in the **modules** tab.